# Zend Framework: Form: How do I create a extremely custom element(s)

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, jquery-ui, zend-form

I will start by saying that I am familiar with Zend Form, and its options/decorators etc, I am looking for some guidance on how best to execute this type of form, also the system uses jQuery, and jQuery-UI so, we can use them too, I should also mention that I do not require advice of the model, i.e. how to save the info, I need help with rendering this type of form, I suspect I will need to use view helpers, and cusom form elements?

**The problem:**

My app has a page which links "products" to a "customer". "products" have a default price, but this can be overridden per customer, this needs to be factored in, I must be able to select from the list of standard products which ones the customer has purchased, override its default price, as well as add any number of custom products on the fly, as such:

**The Form:**

Customer: John Doe

**Products** (X are selected to be linked to customer):

[ ] Blah Product/Service [$32.00]

[X] Foo Service [$23.45]

**Additional products/services** (inputs):

Product Name: [Input] Cost ($): [input] Description: [Input]

Add service: [Button]  <-- Possibly "update the form to add a new set of (above) inputs"

Save customer record: [Button]

Thanks for your help guys, Jay

Comment: i had a similar case where i created a custom gallery element (with add, remove, reorder images) i used a hidden element `gallery` and created a custom decorator + javascript frontend that adds hidden inputs `gallery[]` which later i use as array for processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to me that this form is going to be as custom as you might think.

The trick is in the dynamic addition of products on the fly. Towards that end, see Jeremy Kendall's excellent post on the subject:

[Dynamically Adding Elements to Zend_Form](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/)

Comment: Thanks David, the link to Jeremys post was very useful, I will defiantly be using his method for adding additional elements on the fly. The more I think about it, the more  I realize that method has opened up alot of options for me in terms of managing dynamic forms. Thanks again.